# django_apscheduler remove_all_jobs on django startup

Tags: python, django, apscheduler

I have used django_apscheduler to schedule jobs. And it's working fine. When I start server new job is added and periodically it's doing what I need to do. However if I exit django and start it again then django will fail with error.

> apscheduler.jobstores.base.ConflictingIdError: u'Job identifier (myapp_db.jobs.test_job) conflicts with an existing job'

Basically old job exists in database and new job can not be created.
How can I remove all jobs during django startup.
I notice there is remove_all_job() function in apscheduler but I do not know from where to execute it?

I'm starting job.py from url.py with

> import myapp.jobs

Thanks.

code:

```
import time
import sys
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from kuce_db.models import NjuskaloData, UserVisitedData
import logging
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from django_apscheduler.jobstores import DjangoJobStore, register_events, register_job

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_jobstore(DjangoJobStore(), "default")


def get_trailing_number(s):
    m = re.search(r'\d+$', s)
    return int(m.group()) if m else None

@register_job(scheduler, "interval", seconds=300)
def test_job():
    print("I'm a test job!")



register_events(scheduler)
#
scheduler.start()
print("Scheduler started!")
logging.basicConfig()
```

Comment: make sure you are giving unique id to each job.

Comment: share your code.

Comment: I managed to solve it. There is option replace_existing=True. That will modify defined job.      @register_job(scheduler, "interval", seconds=300, id="test_job", replace_existing=True)

Comment: nice find :-)  and thanks for sharing the solution

Answer (score 2):

use `replace_existing` flag to tell it replace existed job

```
@register_job(scheduler, "interval", seconds=300, replace_existing=True)
def test_job():
    print("I'm a test job!")
```